# How to properly uninstall visual styles in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, desktop-customization

How do I properly uninstall previously installed visual styles for windows 7?
As you can see, my theme is already ruined.
[image]

Comment: Given that there is no proper way to install them in the first place, I'd refer to any recommendations of the program that put those changes there.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution might be to change those icons individually. You should find the original by going to Properties -> Customize -> Change Icon and replace the shell.dll by imageres.dll You'll find a number of icons including the original